# NodeJS: File is imported, but not executed

Tags: node.js, docker

Here is the file structure I have in a NodeJS server:

```
src
 - api
 - - methods
 - - - SOME_API_METHOD.js
 - - - ANOTHER_API_METHOD.js
 - - - THIRD_API_METHOD
 - - - - index.js
 - - - - THIRD_API_METHOD.js <- that's the file that caused a problem
 - - - - someHelperFIleForTheThirdApiMethod.js
 - - - THIRD_API_METHOD.js <- this is the file I added eventually to fix the issue
 - - index.js
 - index.js
 - gateway.js <- that's where the the THIRD_API_METHOD is called from
```

`gateway.js` looks like this:

```js
import api from './api'
export default (req, res) => {
  if (api[req.body.method]) {
    console.log(`all good, execute ${req.body.method}`)
    api[req.body.method](req.body.payload, res)
    console.log('execution finished')

  }
}
```

`src/api/methods/THIRD_API_METHOD/index.js`:

```js
import THIRD_API_METHOD from './THIRD_API_METHOD'
export default THIRD_API_METHOD
```

`src/api/methods/THIRD_API_METHOD/THIRD_API_METHOD.js`:

```js
console.log('THIRD_API_METHOD mounted')
export default async () => {
  console.log('starting THIRD_API_METHOD')
}
```

So, when I've tried to execute `THIRD_API_METHOD`, I was getting only the `all good, execute THIRD_API_METHOD` and `execution finished` logs. Not the others.
I had to add `src/api/methods/THIRD_API_METHOD.js` with the following content to fix the issue:

```
import THIRD_API_METHOD from './THIRD_API_METHOD/THIRD_API_METHOD'
export default THIRD_API_METHOD
```

Then I've got these logs:

```
THIRD_API_METHOD mounted
all good, execute THIRD_API_METHOD
starting THIRD_API_METHOD
execution finished
```

Which means all good.

So, how on earth is this possible?
I've wrapped everything in `try...catch` statements thinking that there is a silent error somewhere. Nothing. Furthermore, I have another method wrapped in a folder just like the `THIRD_API_METHOD` that freaking works . Also the original structure works fine in my local NodeJS 10 environment. It seems to not work only in a docker container deployed to kube engine.

Anyways, how is it possible that all `import`s worked fine yet the file wasn't mounted?

ps I know, I have to do everything in docker, I'm doing this, I just want to know how this issue is possible.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:9.4.0

COPY ./dist /server/dist
COPY ./node_modules /server/node_modules

ENV PORT 80

EXPOSE 80

WORKDIR /server/dist

ENTRYPOINT [ "node", "index.js" ]
```

Comment: If it's Docker- or Kubernetes-related, can you include the relevant artifacts (Dockerfile, Kubernetes Deployment manifest, _etc._)?

Comment: @DavidMaze done. Thanks for your interest 